# What is local IP and remote IP while doing port forwarding?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a web server running on `192.168.1.4:3000` and I want to access this server public internet (outside local network)

Public IP of my router is `203.144.12.34`, I want to forward port 3000 of this to the web server.

Can someone help what should I fill in the fields below? I don't understand what details to put where?

[image: 203.144.12.34]

Comment: Local IP is `192.168.1.1` and local port from and to is `3000` and the remote IP is `203.144.12.34` and the remote port from and to is `3000`.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I tried this but when I check on https://www.yougetsignal.com/ it says PORT 3000 is closed

Comment: You should indicate which router you use. Perhaps in the documentation you will find a NAT (network address translation) or masquerading tab.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to set **port forwarding** on your router (your router IP is 192.168.1.1). You didn't mention what kind of OS you are running on your router, since there could be a different option. But in general: port forwarding (usually if in the firewall).

What you are showing might be a port range forwarding. That can do the job as well. So:

- Name: service name (this is just for you)
- Local IP:  192.168.1.4
- Local port from: 3000
- Local port to: 3000
- Protocol: Either TCP/UDP or Both (both is useful if you don't know,  but usually it is TCP)
- Remote IP: 203.144.12.34 (if blank does not work)
- Remote port from:  3000
- Remote port to: 3000

Then you call your service as 203.144.12.34:3000

If you have a single port forwarding option, you can forward 203.144.12.34:2222 to your local machine 192.168.1.4:3000

Comment: I didn't get what you mentioned in the last sentence regarding port 2222?

Comment: You can play with port numbers and (e.g. port external 2222 to internal port 3000). I use this if I need to switch web servers one is at 80, one at 81 etc, but  the external port is always 80.

Answer (score 1):

The port from/to design ranges of ports, so this should be:

- Local IP : 192.168.1.4
- Local Port from : 3000
- Local Port to : 3000
- Protocol : TCP
- Remote IP : Leave empty (any IP)
- Remote Port from : 3000
- Remote Port to : 3000

Outsiders will connect to your server as `203.144.12.34:3000`.

You may use another value for the remote port.
For HTTP port 80 usually used
(443 for HTTPS if you have set it up),
but this well-known port may be attacked if it's open,
so using another port is safer.